# Front-End to Back-End Compatibility

Tags: android, architecture, client-server

My company wants to distribute an android app with google play store. The problem is our customers host there own back end and those back ends are not always up to date. So when time passes and we distribute new versions of the app it will happen that customers update there app while they don't have the required back end to support the new version.

I'm looking for information how this problem could be solved.

Comment: You can't distribute new app version until supporting backend version is not deployed. As simple as that.

Comment: But we have multiple customers where some already have the new backend. So we could distribute a new version but if some one updates it without having the backend updated we run into problems.